# Refinery CMS User Session issues

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, refinerycms

I have implemented Refinery CMS into a website that I am building.  I an running it on webrick at the moment and I seem to get logged a lot.  It seems to be every 15 minutes.

Has anyone experienced this at all and aware of what the issue could be?

Cheers

Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  Some other people might experience this.

I was making periodic ajax requests from the main site itself without sending the CRSF token.  This was killing any logged in sessions.  I simply added the CRSF token to ajax requests and it stopped logging people out.